# Including hostname in apache logwatch reports

Tags: apache-2.2, logwatch

When hosting multiple domains with apache it's useful to see the logwatch apache output with the virtual host name included, but I only get:

```
 --------------------- httpd Begin ------------------------

 Requests with error response codes
   400 Bad Request
      /: 1 Time(s)
      /robots.txt: 1 Time(s)
```

whereas I would like something like

```
 --------------------- httpd Begin ------------------------

 Requests with error response codes
   400 Bad Request
      example.com/: 1 Time(s)
      example.org/robots.txt: 1 Time(s)
```

How can I achieve this with logwatch?

Comment: Ignor 1st step i thing u can use this http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html

Comment: I have this same issue.  Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (works for me):
Define LogFormat in your `httpd.conf` as

> LogFormat "%h %t [%V] \"%r\" %>s \"%{Referer}i\""

With this particular case, you'll have remote_address, date/time, **[The server name according to the UseCanonicalName setting]**, request, satus code and Referer
(that's my desired format) and then put

> $LogFormat "%h %t %V \"%r\" %>s \"%{Referer}i\""

in your services/http.conf LogWatch file. 
That will

1. make apache put the hostname (Canonical or not, it depends if you use %v or %V)
2. force LogWatch to understand your Apache Access log

Here is an example of the a line in the log output with this particular set of directives:

> 172.3.20.11 [01/Jun/2011:21:00:52 +0200] joomla.local "GET /images/tabs_back.png HTTP/1.1" 404 "http://joomla.local/templates/beez_20/css/personal.css"

If we FOCUS ON ERROR CODES, and how are they treated in LogWatch, here are some changes you can made to */usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/http*:
Add:

> my $my_host = "";
>   my $my_url = "";

Then, about line 462, add this line to save our 4th column (HOST):

> $field{my_host} = $field{$log_fields[3]};

And in line 560, after `fmt_url` is shorten ( `if (length($field{url}) > 60) {...}` ) add:

```
$my_host = $field{$log_fields[3]};
$my_host = substr($my_host,1);
$my_url=$my_host . $fmt_url;
```

Finally, change:

`$needs_exam{$field{http_rc}}{$fmt_url}++;`

by

**`$needs_exam{$field{http_rc}}{$my_url}++;`**

doing so, you'll have this in your Logwatch:

```
Requests with error response codes
404 Not Found
joomla.local/images/tabs_back.png: 3 Time(s)
```

I Hope it helps all you out

Comment: Is the difference between the two definitions "[%V]" vs "%V" intended? Trying to get this to work but no luck so far. I notice the domain in the example log output doesn't have square brackets.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and solved it by changing the `LogFormat` in `apache.conf` (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html)

```
# LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common

# The default output has no info about the server name (%v).
# %m %U%q %H is strictly equivalent to %r.
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%m %v%U%q %H\" %>s %O" common
```

This generates the same output as the default, adding the canonical server name as a prefix. Eg:

```
... "GET www.example.com/apache_pb.gif HTTP/1.0" 200 2326 ...
```

The pro is that you don't need any other customization (eg. on the logwatch side). The con is that you get a few extra characters for each logged line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible if you are logging all virtual domains into the same log file... The apache log will not differentiate between them.

I would also suggest that you take a look at the open source [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net). We moved from logwatch to it, because it is in real time and allow centralized correlation (correlating things like ssh failed login with apache 400 errors).

Answer (score 1):

I found [a blog post detailing this problem and how someone resolved it](http://blog.jachim.be/2009/11/hostnames-in-logwatch-reports/).  Don't know how this will affect log analysis, but noting it here as I found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the hostname using the LogFormat directive in the apache configuration. You can use the following option

```
%{Host}i
```

I found this information in [this link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats). Logwatch should be able to parse custom information.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @Syquus who put me on the right path to modifying the `/usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/http` file.

My file and solution was different but I thought I would share all the same.

I use the standard `vhost_combined` LogFormat that Apache provides that looks like:

`LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined`

which outputs something like:

`example.org:80 1.1.1.1 - - [08/Oct/2013:16:55:01 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 6094 "-" "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux x86_64; Edition Linux Mint) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16"`

I put this in the service configuration override at `/etc/logwatch/conf/services/http.conf`:

```
$logformat = "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```

After finding the approximately correct places to make the changes for @Syquus's solution in `/usr/share/logwatch/scripts/services/http`, I thought simply changing the index from [3] to [0] would work - it didn't. I got incorrect segments of the path and even after traversing the whole hash/array, I didn't find the hostname. Debugging was frustrating because I'm new to Perl, but my solution was to add in matching for the `%v` which was being discarded and then modifying the url further down to include the domain name.

Diff for my solution (I also removed the url truncation), YMMV:

```
--- __http.2013-10-09   2013-10-09 13:11:48.000000000 +0000
+++ http        2013-10-09 14:36:59.000000000 +0000
@@ -132,6 +132,8 @@
 #  Build tables of the log format to parse it and determine whats what
 #

+my $my_url = "";
+
 my $detail = $ENV{'LOGWATCH_DETAIL_LEVEL'} || 0;
 my $ignoreURLs = $ENV{'http_ignore_urls'};
 my $ignoreIPs = $ENV{'http_ignore_ips'};
@@ -379,7 +381,10 @@
 $logformat =~ s/%[\d,!]*/%/g;
 while ($end_loop) {

-   if ($logformat =~ /\G%h/gc) {
+   if ($logformat =~ /\G%v/gc) {
+      $parse_string[$parse_index] .= "(\\S*?)";
+      $parse_field[$parse_index][$parse_subindex++] = "my_host";
+   } elsif ($logformat =~ /\G%h/gc) {
       $parse_string[$parse_index] .= "(\\S*?)";
       $parse_field[$parse_index][$parse_subindex++] = "client_ip";
    } elsif ($logformat =~ /\G%l/gc) {
@@ -437,7 +442,6 @@
 #
 #  Process log file on stdin
 #
-
 while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
    chomp($line);

@@ -580,11 +584,12 @@
          !((defined $ignoreURLs) && ($field{url} =~ /$ignoreURLs/)) &&
          !((defined $ignoreIPs) && ($field{client_ip} =~ /$ignoreIPs/)) ) {
       my $fmt_url = $field{url};
-      if (length($field{url}) > 60) {
-         $fmt_url = substr($field{url},0,42) . " ... " .
-                    substr($field{url},-15,15);
-      }
-      $needs_exam{$field{http_rc}}{$fmt_url}++;
+      #if (length($field{url}) > 60) {
+      #   $fmt_url = substr($field{url},0,42) . " ... " .
+      #              substr($field{url},-15,15);
+      #}
+      $my_url = $field{my_host} . $fmt_url;
+      $needs_exam{$field{http_rc}}{$my_url}++;
    }
    if (defined $field{userid} && $field{userid} ne "-" &&
          (eval $user_display) &&
```

Should I decide to serve up secured content or content on a port other than :80 I might include it in the future. It should be obvious now how.

Hope this helps!

### UPDATE

Made some more changes, fixed a bug. Rather than keep editing this answer you can find my modifications here: https://bitbucket.org/ubiquitypress/logwatch